# install oci8 on php7.3

Tags: oci8, php-7.3

I am trying to compile from source on centos 7.5, oci8-2.2 but it is giving me a huge failed summary report.

```
=====================================================================
TEST RESULT SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Exts skipped    :    0
Exts tested     :   33
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Number of tests :  361               354
Tests skipped   :    7 (  1.9%) --------
Tests warned    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :  342 ( 94.7%) ( 96.6%)
Expected fail   :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests passed    :   12 (  3.3%) (  3.4%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      :   29 seconds
=====================================================================
```

I am not sure if this is normal or if this is meant to show liek this and when i run php locally it does not show oci8 as loaded `php -S 0.0.0.0:33080 -t /var/httpd/domain/domain.com/docs -c /opt/SP/php/etc/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

- Set valid database connection credentials in `oci8/tests/details.inc` before you run the tests.
- Make sure you have the Oracle Client libraries in your search path.  If you are using [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html) then using [`ldconfig`](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst) would be easiest.